# "It is broken." **"to be + ajective" vs "to be + past participle"**

Tags: grammar, verbs, passive-voice

**"to be + ajective" vs "to be + past participle"**

When "to be" is used with words that are both adjectives and the third form of a verb, a sentence like "The windows are broken" seems to be ambiguous to me.

This can be passive like "The windows are broken by protestors every weekend."
or can be simple "to be + adjective" like. "The windows are broken and it's cold.".
Which can means "The windows were broken (p.p.) so they are broken (adjective)!".

Is it true or I am missing something?

Comment: No, they are not always ambiguous. The windows are broken but we can fix them. The windows were broken by kids.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true. You're not missing anything.

In the structure *[ be-verb + past participle ]*, the participle can be acting either as an adjective, or as the main verb in the passive voice. Without any context, it's entirely ambiguous. Only context can resolve the intended meaning.

The default reading is usually that it's an adjective:

> Are the walls painted?

This probably means, "*Do the walls have paint on them?*"

But it's not always clearly an adjective:

> Can you make sure the walls **are painted**?

This sentence is ambiguous, as it could be a request to make sure the walls have paint on them and are not bare, or to make sure that someone paints the walls.

Comment: "or to make sure that someone paints the walls." this one means to get someone to paint the walls on a regular base, right? like yearly. or it can mean just once too?

Comment: Can all " past participles" role as adjectives?

Comment: No. Only some past participles also function as adjectives. I don't believe any of these can be used as adjectives: *occurred, happened, partied, consisted, depended*. Some can operate as adjectives as part of a phrasal verb, like "*I'm all partied out*", or with a preposition, like "*a much depended-upon service*".

Answer (score 2):

The word "broken" can function as both an adjective and a past (or passive) participle. Some sentences have ambiguous parsing. But this usually isn't a problem.

Unless there is a "by" phrase, the simple adjective sense is understood. So without further context "The windows are broken" doesn't mean "Somebody breaks the windows." It means "The windows are not whole".

Answer (score 1):

Probably it is already broken， and u just found it. So, it is alright to say it is broken to state its current status, but "were" is past tense, which means that u are not sure whether the window is good or not.

Comment: You have spelled "you" incorrectly.  When writing answers, you should use formal spelling.

Answer (score 1):

If you just use the word (broken) without any extra context then the listener assumes you're using it as an adjective.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).